# Android Studio, "Adb connection Error:EOF" On linux Mint with Nexus & 2013

Tags: android, linux

I have this error using Android Studio on linux Mint with my Nexus 7 2013 model.

I have tried running ADB fro terminal and there are no devices listed. Also lsusb does not list the Nexus either. I have followed the advice on http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302780 but still no joy. Can anyone please help. It doesn't work with MTP or PTP setting.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED** Having tried many things it turns out the **USB cable** that came with my Nexus 7 2013 was **faulty**. Changing the cable for another bog standard one has fixed it. It works now in Linux Mint and Windows 7 too.